# Angular many rows grid performance in Chrome browser

Tags: html, angular, performance, typescript, google-chrome

I need to make a component witch contains a table with plenty of rows.
All works great on small data. But if items count grows to 2000 and more it becomes lagging. Scrolling and, especially, animation becomes too slow.

I've also tried to set **trackBy** function for **ngFor** but it has no influence to performance in this case.

Please, see **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t72ugv)** example;

As you can see all works perfectly when you use 100 items, on 2000 it stars freezing and on 10,000 it is not usable.

I'm wondering what is the correct way to show grids with lot of data in Angular and how I can increase performance of such kind of pages?

Is there some example of lazy loading implementation can I do it in a way that only visible rows are present as html in DOM and all rows besides scroll are removed from DOM?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have the latest version of Chrome browser: Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I've tried it of different PCs, browsers: it is freezes only in chrome (in chrome on a mac book it works much better then on PC but worse than in safari, as example).

Comment: I just loaded with 10000 elements, and I had little to no load time.. No freezing either

Comment: @JonasPraem, it's weird for me... Which browser did you use to test it? I've been using Chrome (last version) and it's freezes

Comment: Chrome (latest version). When I plot in 10000 in the ´this.populateArr(10000);´ it freezes for maximum 1 sec, until the list is generated

Comment: I have the latest version of Chrome browser and it's lagging. I've tried it of different PCs, browsers: it is freezes only in chrome (in chrome on a mac book it works much better then on PC but worse than in safari, as example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to apply virtual scroll approach when the App dynamically destroys elements as they become invisible. I know two solutions for Angular:

- [angular2-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/rintoj/angular2-virtual-scroll), most popular for now, has some interesting forks
- [ngx-ui-scroll](https://github.com/dhilt/ngx-ui-scroll), is maintained by me, feel free to ask any questions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It can solve this problem, I guess. But it does not give the answer to the question, why I have such problem in Chrome browser only. Also 2k elements is not very big volume of data for nowadays.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it was the only way to "fix" this issue at that moment. But now it seems that the problem is fixed with one of Google Chrome updates.

Comment: @Gobind It should. But look at https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling -- perhaps this is more preferable solution for Material nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is too late answer for you, but for future references and people searching speed improvement in large tables (i have cca. 100 x 40 cells -> icons) here is what i did:

1. cell content moved to separate component (which renders different svg icons in colours depending on data)
2. to both ngFor directives added 'trackBy' algorithm:

*ngFor="let row of rows; trackBy:trackByRowId"
      ....
*ngFor="let cell of row.cells; trackBy:trackByCellId"

and those functions are like:

```
  trackByRowId(index, item) {
    return item.rowId;
  }

  trackByCellId(index, item) {
    return item.cellColId;
  }
```

My rendering time went from cca. 10-20 seconds to only 1 second (editing, moving and jumping to few days after or before...).